DataGrid Removal
I am trying to create a management app for rugby players and I'm trying to create a REMOVE/ELIMINATE button. But there's a problem.
This is the code I have so far
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Tem a certeza que quer eliminar este registo?", "AVISO!",     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        jogadoresBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
        this.Validate();
        this.jogadoresBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.apprugbyDataSet);
    }
    else if (res == DialogResult.No) //eu sei que posso ter só else mas eu gosto mais assim
    {
    
    }

With this, the table only removes the FIRST player, instead of the selected one.
Thank you all once again, and have a nice day everyone
